Is there are a testcontainer class for greenplum db?
I want to start a Greenplum DB as a testcontainer
https://greenplum.org/
There is a org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer already available. Is there an analogue for Greenplum ? Or do I have no choice than to implement it myself by extending org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer or even org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer ? I couldn't find any solutions in internet.
If so what image should be used at best? Maybe datagrip/greenplum:6.8 ?
Asking because I have to use some SQL-scripts which can only be applied to Greenplum, not to PostgreSQL.
PS:
I've implemented a testcontainer class based on JdbcDatabaseContainer, but it starts ca. 90 seconds. Would be great to know how it can be accelerated? Maybe by using another image?...

I've implemented a class based on org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.
import org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

public class GreenplumTestContainer extends JdbcDatabaseContainer<GreenplumTestContainer> {
    private static final String IMAGE_NAME = "datagrip/greenplum:6.8";
    private static GreenplumTestContainer container;
    public static final Integer POSTGRESQL_PORT = 5432;

    private GreenplumTestContainer(String imageName) {
        super(DockerImageName.parse(imageName).asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres"));
        this.addExposedPort(POSTGRESQL_PORT);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDriverClassName() {
        return "org.postgresql.Driver";
    }

    @Override
    public String getJdbcUrl() {
        String additionalUrlParams = this.constructUrlParameters("?", "&");
        return "jdbc:postgresql://" + this.getHost() + ":" + this.getMappedPort(POSTGRESQL_PORT) + "/" + "testdb" + additionalUrlParams;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return "tester";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getTestQueryString() {
        return "select 1";
    }

    public static GreenplumTestContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new GreenplumTestContainer(IMAGE_NAME);
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //do nothing, JVM handles shut down
    }
}

and run it with reuse option to prevent it from stopping after the test so that it doesn't need to be started (takes ca. 90 seconds) before the next test execution.
@Container
@ServiceConnection
public static final JdbcDatabaseContainer<GreenplumTestContainer> databaseContainer =
        GreenplumTestContainer.getInstance().withReuse(true);

But for this to work you also need to add the option:
testcontainers.reuse.enable=true

to your .testcontainers.properties which must be in your home directory.
